# How to safeguard image URL?

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

Have lots of images stored at Azure Blob Storage. Frontend Angular display them like:

```
<div *ngFor="let img of list;">
  <img src="/AzPath/{{img}}">
</div>
```

Using `CanActivate` safeguarding route inside Angular:

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthGuardServiceService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public router: Router) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean
{
...
}
```

`withCredentials: true` in proxy.conf.js to send in cookies as session is managed by database. Also Azure firewall rule for Storage Account only allows certain IP.

I noticed the `GET` request to nodejs (Azure Function) for image `src` URL don't send in cookies, but I prefer not to access database with session cookie for performance. I can think of is a signed URL which is also validated by node.

What's needed is to prevent authenticated users altering the `src` to access other images not supposed to see. For example user A is permitted to see `A-1.png` but is not `B-1.png`. My thought for a signedURL is node should check if this URL is tempered. I'm opened to any idea not limited to signed URL, all input is appreciated, with code sample is a PLUS.

Angular v12, nodejs v14

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to not make the images public to the web, right? You can apply one of the following methods and I believe either one will work for you:

1- work with a reverse proxy. Your front end will use the reverse proxy url, and it will be responsible to serve the real image to you. As a drawback, you can't leverage CDN to serve the images for you.

2-Work with Managed identities and Storage Account firewall rules, this way, only your backend can access the images and you won't need to worry about the image url. You can read more about it in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal%2Cprogramming-language-nodejs)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. To prevent authenticated user A alters the `src` to access other images not belonged to him. For example user A is permitted to see `A-1.png` but is not `B-1.png`. My thought for a signedURL is node should check if this URL is tempered.

Comment: I see ....so I believe #1 should work

Comment: Great, I haven't used reverse proxy, can you provide some links I can get started? Thank you